# c++ testing if one file is older than a set of files

Tags: c++, timestamp, filesystems

I am creating a cache for some data, but of course I want the cache to become invalid if any of the source files from which the cache is made is modified. TO that effect I made this function:

```
bool CacheIsValid(
    const std::string& cache_shader_path,
    const std::vector<std::string>& shader_paths)
{
    // This is really messy because of the std stuff, the short of it is:
    // Find the youngest file in the shader paths, then check it against the
    // timestamp of the cached file.
    std::time_t youngest_file_ts = std::time(nullptr);
    for(auto file : shader_paths)
    {
        std::time_t current_timestamp =
            std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(
                std::chrono::file_clock::to_sys(fs::last_write_time(file)));
        double time_diff = difftime(youngest_file_ts, current_timestamp);
        if(time_diff > 0) youngest_file_ts = current_timestamp;
    }

    // All this is doing is comparing the youngest file time stamp with the cache.
    return fs::exists(cache_shader_path)
        && (difftime(youngest_file_ts, std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(
            std::chrono::file_clock::to_sys(fs::last_write_time(cache_shader_path)))) < 0);
}
```

I don't know what I did wrong but that is always returning true even when the input files are modified. I am checking the timestamps using `stat` and the files on disk are objectively younger than the cache file, I also tested that the inputs to this function are correct, and they are.

Comment: lets try `std::time_t youngest_file_ts = td::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(
                std::chrono::file_clock::to_sys(fs::last_write_time(shader_paths.at(0))))` make sure check !shader_paths.empty() is true

Comment: Yup that was it, I am stupid

Comment: if it worked I will create answer for it, could you please accept that for me ?

Comment: And i think if(time_diff < 0) also

Comment: Yup I will accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

due to you want to find youngest_file_ts -> find most recently timestamp (greater number) of a changing file however

```
double time_diff = difftime(youngest_file_ts, current_timestamp);
if(time_diff > 0) youngest_file_ts = current_timestamp; // find greater number one
```

after the for loop youngest_file_ts is oldest timestamp of a changing file
therefor

```
(difftime(youngest_file_ts, std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(
          std::chrono::file_clock::to_sys(fs::last_write_time(cache_shader_path)))) < 0) alway true.
```

it should be change like

```
    if (shader_paths.empty()) {
        return false
    } else {
//initialize youngest_file_ts as last_write_time of first element in shader_paths
        std::time_t youngest_file_ts = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(
                 std::chrono::file_clock::to_sys(fs::last_write_time(shader_paths.at(0))); 
        for (auto file : shader_paths)
        {
            std::time_t current_timestamp = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(
                std::chrono::file_clock::to_sys(fs::last_write_time(file)));
            double time_diff = difftime(youngest_file_ts, current_timestamp);
            if (time_diff < 0) youngest_file_ts = current_timestamp;
        }
        // All this is doing is comparing the youngest file time stamp with the cache.
        return fs::exists(cache_shader_path)
            && (difftime(youngest_file_ts, std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(
                std::chrono::file_clock::to_sys(fs::last_write_time(cache_shader_path)))) < 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you're jumping through a lot of hoops that make this tremendously more difficult than it needs to be. `filesystem::last_write_time` returns a `time_point<someclock>`<sup>1</sup> , which supports comparison. As such, at least as far as I can see, there's no reason to do the long, drawn-out conversion to `time_t`, then using `difftime` to do the comparison.

If I understand the idea of what you're doing, you want to ascertain that the one file is at least as new as any of the files named in the vector. To do that a bit more directly, I'd write code something along this general line:

```cpp
bool isNewer(std::string const &file, std::vector<std::string> const &otherFiles) {
    auto newest = std::max_element(otherFiles.begin(), otherFiles.end(), 
        [&](std::string const &a, std::string const &b) {           
            return fs::last_write_time(a) > fs::last_write_time(b);
        });

    return fs::last_write_time(file) >= fs::last_write_time(*newest);
}
```

I may have misunderstood the direction you want one or both comparisons done, in which case this may not be right--but if so, changing the comparison(s) to match your requirements should be trivial.

---

1. where `someclock` is some arbitrary type that meets a few specified requirements for C++17, or `std::chrono::file_clock` for C++20.